# Removing an object from TreeSet

Tags: java, collections, treeset

So I have the following relevant code:

```
public static TreeSet<Object> set;



public static void remove(Object object){
    for (Object o : set){
        if (o.equals(object)){
            System.out.println("removing " + o);
            set.remove(o);
        }
    }
}
```

I add a few objects to that TreeSet, then I call remove with a certain object1 as an argument. The object1 is in the set, as

```
removingobject1
```

is printed out.

Yet, when I then print out the whole set after that using a for-loop like this:

```
for (Object o: set){
        System.out.println(o);
    }
```

It still prints out the whole set including object1. It was clearly in the collection before, which Java was able to recognize, yet calling set.remove(o) results in absolutely nothing.

edit: I tried to keep the question as general as possible, but here are the objects that I'm using:

```
public class Player implements Comparable<Player>{

public String firstname;
public String lastname;
public int value;
public Position position;



public Player(String firstname, String lastname, int value, Position position){
this.firstname = firstname;
this.lastname = lastname;
this.value = value;
this.position = position;

}

public String toString(){
    return(firstname + " " + lastname")
}


public int compareTo(Player player){
    if (this.value > player.value){
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your object implement `hashCode()`? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please show some code that shows manipulations of your set and objects. How do you create your objects, how do they implement hashCode(), how do you add them to the set?

Comment: You are using Object Class are you also setting any property?  If would be easier for us to help you if you paste your code here.

Comment: A `TreeSet`  needs either objects that implement the `Comparable` interface or a `Comparator` to compare the elements. Which do you use?

Comment: @shmosel it does not implement hashCode().

Comment: But it does implement `equals()`?

Comment: Return 0 when this.value == player.value in your compareTo(...) method and it will work.

Comment: @shmosel it doesn't - I assumed this wouldn't be a problem since the `o.equals(object)` part worked fine.

Comment: @NataljaOlefire is right. Your `compareTo()` is broken when both values are 0. See the contract for [`Comparable.compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-): *The implementor must ensure `sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x))` for all `x` and `y`.*

Comment: @NataljaOlefire Thank You! Problem solved. :)

Comment: @shmosel She was indeed right, your suggestions fixed my problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @shmosel not really. compareTo should return 0 when objects are equal. (Math.signum(0) == -Math.signum(0)) is true.

Comment: @NataljaOlefire My bad, I meant when both values are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Your remove method could look like:

```
public static void remove(Object object){
   set.remove(o);
}
```

Method remove removes element if it is present in the set, and returns true if it was removed. You should not modify your set during the iteration ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)):

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator method are fail-fast:
>   if the set is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in
>   any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator
>   will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of
>   concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly,
>   rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an
>   undetermined time in the future.

Comment: This is true, but doesn't answer the question. And I suspect the iteration was just to prove the element is in the set.

Comment: In this case then it should throw ConcurrentModificationException as one element is removed and the modCount value is changed so the iterator should fail.

Comment: I have actually tried it this way and somehow it didn't work. I implemented the for loop to see if Java recognizes that the object is still in the set (which it is). If remove(o) actually worked naturally I'd delete the unnecessary for loop. ;)